# UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sqlite3

> tengo un error al asignar una variable a un diccionario, para presentar la consulta

```
 s={}
        s["nombre"]=fila["nombre"]
        s["autor"]=fila["autor"]
        s["year"]=str(fila["year"])
    lista.append(s)`
```

Comment: Hola Adán, ¿dónde defines `s` , exactamente? Considera agregar un  [mcve], deberías además agregar la traza completa del error, no solo la última línea. La variable `s` no está definida en ese espacio de nombres., pero con solo ese código (con problemas de identación o lineas que faltan además) y sin la traza es imposibles saber cuál es.

Comment: s={}, #alli se define,

Comment: Si, pero ese código como tal no es ejecutable siquiera, que la definas en alguna parte del código no significa que exista cuando haces `s["nombre"]`, si la defines en un condicional por ejemplo puede no existir si el condicional no se cumplió, si la defines dentro de una función y no la haces global, fuera de ella (en otra función o a nivel de módulo) no existirá tampoco porque es una variable local a la función, etc... Lo que es seguro es que cuando intentas usarla la variable no existe en ese namespace, para saber la causa se necesita más código.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu respuesta